# how import compute_CD in orange3

Tags: python

i'm trying plot cd diagram but i don't understand why the error appears
before, i install orangee with command `!pip install orange3`

```
import Orange
from Orange.evaluation import compute_CD
```

this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-8ddf671e8aa9> in <module>
      1 from scipy.stats import wilcoxon,friedmanchisquare,rankdata
      2 import Orange
----> 3 from Orange.evaluation import compute_CD

ImportError: cannot import name 'compute_CD' from 'Orange.evaluation' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/Orange/evaluation/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

before, i install orangee with command `!pip install orange3`

```
import Orange
from Orange.evaluation import compute_CD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version of `Orange` (3.34.1 at the time of writing) does not include the `compute_CD` function anymore. I don't know the reason, and I don't know whether it will come back in future releases.

For the time being, you might want to install an older version of `Orange` that still has the function, for example:

`pip install orange3==3.30`

Which includes `compute_CD` and is compatible with Python 3.9.

If you are working with an older Python release, older versions of Orange should do the job, e.g. Orange 3.25 is compatible with Python 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8.